# Prototype select element with id that contains specific character

Tags: magento, select, input, prototype

I have a select box like this:

```
<select id="_item13country_id" name="address[13][country_id]" class="required-entry countries required-entry select required-entry select">
 <option value=""> </option>
 <option value="TH" selected="selected">Thailand</option>
</select>
```

I need to select that by using prototype to find which element that contains

> country_id

How can I do that ?. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$$("[id*=country_id]")
```

This will select all the elements where `id` is `country_id`